# section in infopath form

Tags: infopath

I ve created a SharePoint List with my columns, and i clicked on customize form to create an infopath form from my list. one of the columns on my sharePoint list is of type choice, which is a dropdowlist on infopath form. This dropdown has option1 and option2. the requirement is that when you select option1, textBox1, textBox2 and textBox3 should be visible on the infopath form, but if option2 is selected then textBox1, textBox2 and textBox3 should be hidden.

all these feilds are contained on one table in the form, so for me to be able to hide and show these fields based on the options selected i've broken this table into two tables. with table1 having the options dropdown, and the table2 containing textBox1, textBox2 and textBox3. 
Ive added a section which contains table2 so that it can be easier for me to hide and show the fields in table2 by just hiding the section based n the option selected. Now my problem is that i am not able to rename or use section on my conditional formating. if I go to section properties the section name is disabled.

Please advise if there is another better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Infopath forms of type/compatibility  Sharepoint List Form have unmodifiable and locked schema. In other words, take it or leave (i.e. use or abandon) it as it is.

Also I do not see how you could have possibly used the name of a section in infopath list form.

On the other hand, what you described is nothing more than enabling a user to hide or unhide a section which is already provided by in-built functionality in section properties:

- Allow users to insert the section
- Show insert button and hint text:

[image]

And running it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanx Gennady,, :) your answer really helped me,, each an everyday I am leaning something on Infopath/ SharePoint